# C pointers 2 dimensional move to top

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm quite new to pointers and C in general.

```
void moveUpToTop(int num, int dim, int index) {
    int i,j;
    double *temp = w[index];
    double *zero = w[0];
    for(i = index; i > 0; i--) {
        double *ptrA = w[i];
        double *ptrB = w[i - 1];
        for(j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            *(ptrA + j) = *(ptrB + j);
        }
    }

    for(j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
        *(zero + j) = *(temp + j);
    }
}
```

Having this with a 2-dimensional array w, defined as double **w. I'd like to move some array value with index "index" up to the top of the array using pointers because that is the exercise we've got to do.

first of all, I'm saving one of the array locations, then I'm moving all array locations one level up.
What am I doing wrong?

Given to me is the following code in what I have to design the sort function.

```
double **w;
int main (void) {
    int dim, num;
    int i, j;

    scanf ("%d %d", &dim, &num);
    w = calloc (num, sizeof (double *));
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        w[i] = calloc (dim + 1, sizeof (double));

        int sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            scanf ("%le", &w[i][j]);
            sum += w[i][j] * w[i][j];
        }
        w[i][dim] = sqrt(sum);
    }

    sort(num, dim);
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            printf("%e ", w[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `double **` does not define a two-dimensional array. It's a pointer to a pointer. It only very slightly behaves like an array.

Comment: `double **` is not a 2D array and cannot point to one. Use a 2D array if you need one. Read [ask], provide a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean by "move some array value with index "index" up to the top of the array"?

Comment: @StoryTeller and Olaf you are right, I have edited and added the code that is provided to me to do this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you save a pointer to the original data but you don't save the data itself.

```
double *temp = w[index];  // Here you save the pointer
```

but in the first loop you overwrite data:

```
for(i = index; i > 0; i--) {
    double *ptrA = w[i];            // Same as w[index] in first loop
    double *ptrB = w[i - 1];
    for(j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
        *(ptrA + j) = *(ptrB + j);  // The data pointed to by w[index] is overwritten
                                    // in the first loop
```

So this code is no copying the original data at index:

```
for(j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
    *(zero + j) = *(temp + j);  // Data at index have been overwritten
                                // so this doesn't do what you want
}
```

To fix this, it is not sufficient to save a pointer to `index`(i.e. `double *temp = w[index];`). Instead you need to save all data that `double *temp = w[index];` points to.

So you need to `malloc` some data to hold a copy. Then copy the data in a for-loop and use the copied data when restoring to `zero`.

BTW: Also notice that the code given to you uses a very ugly construct. It is allocating `dim + 1` to save an extra double. Your move function therefore also need to use `dim + 1` instead of just `dim`